# php shell_exec won't run a working shell script?

Tags: php, python, bash, apache, shell

I want to run a python script independent of apache. I wrote a shell script containing the following

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo nohup python dejavu/sniffer.py $1 $2 $3 > /var/log/apache2/sniffer.log 2>&1 & echo $!
```

for some reason the following does nothing however, it does return a PID.

```
$cmd = ' ./sniffer.sh '.$audioStream." ".$content_type." ".$bit_rate;
$command = escapeshellcmd($cmd);
$out = shell_exec($command)
```

The shell script works fine on it's own. exec($cmd) does nothing as well.

I have checked the disabled functions in the ini file, thats not the issue.

Comment: Does your PHP/Apache user have permissions to run said file?

Comment: 4 -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  100 Jul 23 15:06 sniffer.sh as you can see the file can be executed by anyone. Ditto for the python file.

Comment: I believe your problem is sudo

Comment: i removed sudo from the bash script. makes no difference

Comment: What does `sniffer.log` say?

Comment: It says nothing, i thought it would print an error there, but its empty. When i run the script alone the stdout does write to log. But, when the script is called from php, nothing happens.

Comment: If you delete it, is it recreated as an empty file?

Comment: it's never recreated

Comment: That most likely means that the web user doesn't have access to write the log file. Write it to `/tmp` or similar so you can see the error messages. Unless you've specifically gone through the trouble of configuring sudo access to that command for the web user, that's probably why it's failing, but the error messages will be helpful.

Comment: ' ./sniffer.sh ' .. what is the PWD when run from PHP? Is this a path problem? Just guessing as there isnt any info on what actual error/issue you encounter.

Comment: It runs from /var/www/html